# Identify device

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, relay

[image]

Everybody can help me identify this device in red circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mark only tells that it's a unidirectional component at first. Most of the time that means a diode of any type - not telling about the type of diode.

Could be small signal switching diode or a Zener or a TVS. You could desolder and measure a bit, or follow the traces to understand the schematic better.

Answer (score 6):

Judging from the symbol underneath the device it's a diode.

Comment: D5 looks ... interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a TVS diode, hard to say without any more information. If right leg is going to GND, I'd say 85 % that is TVS or Zener diode.